# How to stop Angular from reformatting my stylesheet in browser

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to be able to jump to the right line numbers when inspecting the styles. The line numbers I get when inspecting my Angular application in Chrome (or FireFox/Firebug) are different from the line numbers in my source, though. When I jump to the Sources view in Chrome I see that my stylesheet is reformatted. How can I turn off this reformatting by Angular?

I'm using Grunt and Bower to build my app. Still, the file loaded in index.html is exactly the same file as I'm editing. So I think the reformatting of the stylesheet is in-memory and is performed by some script. Some Angular script, maybe?

Comment: It's not angular, it's your browser. Firebug does it, native FF debugger does it, Chrome debugger does it **afaik**

Comment: @Johnny000 I just checked with a non-angular application: Chrome debugger leaves my stylesheet as is and doesn't change line numbers. The only time I see this behavior is with my Angular application (with Grunt/Bower). Also the problem is consistent in IE 11: reformatting only occurs with the Angular app.

Comment: Have you looked into your Grunt/Bower work-flows? Are you doing any CSS pre-processing, concatenation, or minification?

Comment: @Sunil I surely did. Gruntfile.js mentiones css files here: initConfig: watch: styles: files, and in livereload. Then again, it seems illogical that Grunt would change anything to main.css that I would not see in my editor. Main.css is the file that is loaded in index.html. So again I think some in-memory script action causes my problem. No, I am not doing any minificatio or concatenation.

Comment: After some investigation I found that Grunt has tasks that place prefixed stylesheets (beautified?) in a directory .tmp. These .css files are exactly the ones I see in FireBug (the path seems to point to styles/, not .tmp/, but in fact is to .tmp). I tried uncommenting cssmin: in Gruntfile.js, to no avail.